# How to loop through a list and make a dictionary

Tags: python

```
files = ['bob.csv', 'mike.csv', 'sally.csv']
file_type = "excel"
units = "mm"
bin_size = 1
filter_amount = .512
gecko_file = "n"


for file in files:
    d = {file:
         {
        'file_type': file_type,
        'units': units,
        'bin_size':bin_size,
        'filter_amount':filter_amount,
        'gecko_file':gecko_file
        }
    }
    
d
```

Has this output:

```
{'sally.csv': {'file_type': 'excel',
  'units': 'mm',
  'bin_size': 1,
  'filter_amount': 0.512,
  'gecko_file': 'n'}}
```

I'm wondering why there isn't an output for every 'file' in 'files'. I'd want my output to be:

```
{'sally.csv': {'file_type': 'excel',
  'units': 'mm',
  'bin_size': 1,
  'filter_amount': 0.512,
  'gecko_file': 'n'}}

{'mike.csv': {'file_type': 'excel',
  'units': 'mm',
  'bin_size': 1,
  'filter_amount': 0.512,
  'gecko_file': 'n'}}

{'bob.csv': {'file_type': 'excel',
  'units': 'mm',
  'bin_size': 1,
  'filter_amount': 0.512,
  'gecko_file': 'n'}}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Because you overwrite d in every iteration instead of adding to it.

Comment: Use `d[file] = {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add print(d) inside the for loop only then it will print all three dictionaries.

```
files = ['bob.csv', 'mike.csv', 'sally.csv']
file_type = "excel"
units = "mm"
bin_size = 1
filter_amount = .512
gecko_file = "n"


for file in files:
    d = {file:
         {
        'file_type': file_type,
        'units': units,
        'bin_size':bin_size,
        'filter_amount':filter_amount,
        'gecko_file':gecko_file
        }
    }
    print(d)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: But still the final dictionary `d` will contain just one entry.